# I just started using Emacs 24.3.1 with System Verilog and I want to fix some default behavior

Tags: system-verilog, emacs24

Specifically, I'd like to keep the syntax formatting but turn off auto-indenting and auto-newline after semicolons. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following lines to your emacs configuration file (usually .emacs or .emacs.el or .emacs.d/init.el in your home directory).

Note that it is sufficient to just remove ";" mapping to achieve both your objectives. But if you ever find it useful to have auto-indent on ";" but no newline, you can just set verilog-auto-newline to nil.

```
;; do not add newline on semicolon
(setq verilog-auto-newline nil)
;; remove ";" mapping so that there are no electric effects
(add-hook 'verilog-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key verilog-mode-map ";" nil)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess with editing your `.emacs` file, you can do `M-x customize-group verilog-mode-indent` and you'll get an interactive menu that shows you all of the options and lets you configure them.